# How to disable 'delete files' confirmation?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

Is there a way to disable the Windows confirmation prompt when deleting files to the recycle bin?

I *do* want the prompt to remain when Shift-deleting (i.e. not to the recycle bin).

[I'm using Windows-XP but assume the question to be interesting for other versions as well]

Edited to add:

The solution is indeed to disable the recycle bin check box "Display delete confirmation dialog". This is a confusing text because it indeed *does not* skip the prompt when shift-deleting. That check box *is limited to recycle bin deletes*. I had assumed it to be 'global'.

Thanks
Jan

Comment: Can only test on windows 8:
 Open Recycle bin and right click inside it - click on properties and click 'Don't move file to recycle bin delete immediately' then click the 'Display delete conformation code' this removes the item without using the recycle bin and asks 'Are you sure you want to delete this item permanently' before deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIcrosoft Support KB 320031,
[HOW TO: Bypass the Recycle Bin When You Delete Files and Folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320031)

> Permanently Bypass the Recycle Bin
>   You can permanently bypass the Recycle Bin by changing the configuration of the Recycle Bin:
>
> 1. Right-click the Recycle Bin, and then click Properties.
> 2. In the Recycle Bin Properties dialog box,
>      click to select the Do not move files to the Recycle Bin.
> 3. Remove files immediately when deleted check box.
> 4. Click OK.
>
> You can also configure Windows XP to skip the confirmation message
>   whether or not you are using the Recycle Bin. In the Recycle Bin
>   Properties dialog box, click to clear the Display delete confirmation
>   dialog check box, and then click OK.

<sub>ps: I moved away from XP some time back; can't confirm this. Note that a permanent bypass might be dangerous.</sub> 
<sup>Tell me if it works for you.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the Recycle Bin and select `properties`.
2. Uncheck the `Display delete confirmaion dialog box`.
3. Click `Apply` then OK.